# Can drush return if site is in maintenance_mode?

Tags: drush, maintenance-mode

To work in parallel with another team, I've copied via ftp the working Drupal 7 app and mysql database and am trying to get it to run. I've cleared the cache and drush happily reports connecting to the db but the home page responds with a 500 error about

```
Recoverable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to image_resize() must be an instance of stdClass, boolean given, called in /media/psf/Home/apps/newdom/sites/all/modules/image_resize_filter/image_resize_filter.module on line 515 and defined in image_resize() (line 279 of /media/psf/Home/apps/newdom/includes/image.inc).
```

I'm unable to see anything and to login. While I'm tracking down why that error is thrown, I can see in the page inspector that the css is suggesting the app is in maintenance mode. OK, looking at the drush help commands I enter:

```
drush vset --exact maintenance_mode 0
```

And it returns that maintenance_mode set to "0". But the page still looks like it's in maintenance.

My question is, can I send a command through drush to test if the site is in maintenance mode or not? I've tried leaving off the last parameter but that is required. I don't see it in the help page so maybe it does not. Drush status does not have a property for that in its list. Is there a way to verify an app is in maintenance mode by the command line?

Comment: I think that error has nothing to do with maintenance mode, when you access yoursite.com/user you are still getting the error? i think if drush says maintenance_mode set to "0" it is set to 0, you can check drush [http://www.drushcommands.com/drush-5x/variable/variable-get] (variable-get) but it will return 0

Comment: Yes, you are right. drush variable-get maintenance_mode returns 0. If you could place that as an answer I can mark it as the answer. thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think if drush says maintenance_mode set to "0" it is set to 0,  none the less you can check drush [variable-get](http://drushcommands.com/drush-5x/variable/variable-get) but it will return 0